# Getting null when i sending mail "$mail->send();" from send function

Tags: php, opencart, phpmailer

I trying to send mail from my server. I have set the mail cc,to,bcc,message and everything in my mail function. While sending mail this function "$mail->send();" returning "null" I don't what is the reason behind could you please help me to resolve this issue ?

my mail function is

```
$mail = new Mail();
        $mail->protocol = $this->config->get('config_mail_protocol');
        $mail->parameter = $this->config->get('config_mail_parameter');
        $mail->smtp_hostname = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_hostname');
        $mail->smtp_username = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_username');

        $mail->smtp_password = html_entity_decode($this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_password'), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        $mail->smtp_port = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_port');
        $mail->smtp_timeout = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_timeout');

        $mail->setTo($to);
        $mail->setBcc("test@gmail.com");
        $mail->setFrom($data["email"]);
        $mail->setSender(html_entity_decode($data["full_name"], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
        $mail->setSubject($subject);
        $mail->setText($body);

        $mailData= $mail->send();
var_dump($mailData); die;
```

the `$mailData` its showing null.

Thank you.

Comment: Please add relevant code to the question, i.e. where you initialize and use $mail variable. Also check $mail->ErrorInfo, it may contain additional information.

Comment: yes, Just now i have added after $mail->send(); var_dump($mail->ErrorInfo);die; like this but its showing "Notice: Undefined property: Mail::$ErrorInfo" .

Comment: Hello! Welcome to *StackOverflow*. Please go through [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking a question. Also, please provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code that you have tried so far. Show some effort that you have put and I'm sure we'll be able to help you from there on.

Comment: Hi, I have added my mail send function code snippet. how can i see the errros from the $mail function?

Comment: Their documentation suggests you should enable exceptions by passing `true` to the `PHPMailer` constructor

Comment: Am using opencart "Version 2.3.0.2" mail function how we can display error log?

Comment: I replace the Mail() with phpmailer() now  its working fine. thanks for your suggestions.